# Access input value of 1st form into second form on same page (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC latest version.

I have one form which has radio buttons values and a save button - each time page load, it brings values from database and it load the values to radio button which is working fine on get. I have a back link hyper link on the same page and a button to save new values of radios if changes. The back link resides way top on the page and this form is quite at the bottom.

HTML

```
<div class="width-container">
    <a class="back-link" id="all-subjects-link" href="/Subjects">All Subjects</a> 
</div>

-- ------------

<div class=formgroup>
    <form method="post" id="aform" novalidate>
       <div class="radios__item">
           <input class="radio_input" id="FirstRadio" asp-for="RadioValues" type="radio" value="1">
           Physics
       </div>
       <div class="radios__item">
           <input class="radio_input" id="SecondRadio" asp-for="RadioValues" type="radio" value="2">
           Chemistry
       </div>
       <div class="radios__item">
           <input class="radio_input" id="ThirdRadio" asp-for="RadioValues" type="radio" value="3">
           Biology
       </div>
                  
       <div class="button-group">
            <button  id="save-button" type="submit" asp-page-handler="UpdateSubjects">Confirm subject</button>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

A user can select the subject again and submit the button which saves into db.

Now, if someone changes radio button and without hitting save button, if he tries to click on the Back link, he should get an ASP.NET validation error messages (`Model.State` validation). The problem for me is, I cannot use javascript here and it has to be server side or a very little java script.

I thought to use a button instead of Back hyperlink, and submit a post, but this Back exists way up from the form, so I will need to use the second form here.

I have two questions:

1. Can I still do with back hyperlink (not a button and not a second form logic) a post and do server side model state validation checks on radio buttons values. If yes, how?
2. If I am using a back button now - How do I access  radio form values into another form on the same page?

Here is my second form

```
<form method="post" id="validate--form" novalidate>
    <div class="button-group">
        <button class="button " id="back-validation-button" type="submit" asp-page-handler="ValidationSubject">All applications</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Post method for this form

```
// Validation
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostValidationSubjectAsync() 
{  
    // How to access radio button values from form 1 into here. 
    SubjectModel subjectmodel = TempData.Get<SubjectModel>("SubjectModel"); //Value from db
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sending two formValue within a single controller?

Comment: Yes, single controller

Comment: help Anyone please ?

Comment: `"Can I still do with back hyperlink (not a button and not a second form logic) a post and do server side model state validation checks on radio buttons values."` Well, using back hyperlink do you want to post values to `OnPostValidationSubjectAsync` controller?